# UDP socket in native kotlin multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor, kotlin-native

I am making a native multiplatform app with kotlin.

The thing is I need a udp socket. I saw there was some sort of this in the poesix package but it wasn't really practical to use...

I read there was KTor network.. how could/can I use this?
Are there alternatives?
What should I do?

:)
Thank y'all! Have a great day!

Comment: You can find the documentation about Ktor native sockets here: https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think it is not ready to use socket in KMM, they say it is experimental and It exposes a suspending API that uses java.nio under the hood. Even the official examples, they import libraries from Java (so it is not supported in KMM),  e.g: https://github.com/ktorio/ktor-documentation/blob/2.3.8/codeSnippets/snippets/sockets-client-tls/src/main/kotlin/com/example/Application.kt